# If input value = "word"

Tags: jquery, input, keypress

I have an **input** that I need on enter `keypress` to check `if input = no, nope, none` *(and so on, a number of words I select)* the **#preview** container to have the value **x**, else, the preview container have the value **y**.

What I have so far doesn't work and I can't figure out why :
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/1bk0jqoy/)

Script:

```
$('input').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==13){

        if(('input').val() =='no'){

        $('#preview').html('No email').fadeIn(800);

        }, else {

        $('#preview').html('Email: ' + '<strong style="color:#fd8a64;">' + $(this).val().toLowerCase() + '</strong>').fadeIn(800);

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Check you console always for errors.. The 2 syntax errors in your code are clearly stated in console. Also, you can use `this.value` for `input[type=text]` instead of a jQuery `.val`

Comment: @vega Forgot to check...I was frustrated as to why it's not working...Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this code:

```
$('input').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==13){

        if($(this).val() =='no'){

        $('#preview').html('No email').fadeIn(800);

        } else {

        $('#preview').html('Email: ' + '<strong style="color:#fd8a64;">' + $(this).val().toLowerCase() + '</strong>').fadeIn(800);

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the " $ " before the input.. I will accept your answer since it's the first and it works :D & a +1 :D

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your code. Missing **$** before ('input') and comma before else statement.

```
$('input').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==13){

        if($('input').val() =='no'){

            $('#preview').html('No email').fadeIn(800);

        } else {

            $('#preview').html('Email: ' + '<strong style="color:#fd8a64;">' + $(this).val().toLowerCase() + '</strong>').fadeIn(800);

        }
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1bk0jqoy/2/

Comment: You don't need a comma before else statement ^^ but +1 for working example :D Thanks, and i can't believe I forgot the $...

Answer (score 1):

You need to try replace ('input') with $(this)

```
$('input').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==13){

        if(($this).val() =='no'){

        $('#preview').html('No email').fadeIn(800);

        }, else {

        $('#preview').html('Email: ' + '<strong style="color:#fd8a64;">' + $(this).val().toLowerCase() + '</strong>').fadeIn(800);

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Well yup, that certainly does the trick, after your answers I realized that I forgot the $ before the (input)...silly me, anyhow, +1 for the answer ! Thanks !

Comment: gladt it helps :) @Alin